# SQL syntax for splitting one column in to two

Tags: sql

I have a sample database that uses the following

```
select buying_list 
from customers
```

results: `{"sellingUnit":1,"buyingUnit":2}` as a string

how would i split it in to two columns with one column selling unit having the value of 1 and the other column with buying unit as 2?

Comment: Which [DBMS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DBMS) product are you using? Postgres? Oracle? "SQL" is just a query language, not the name of a specific database product.

Comment: The schema is horribly broken.  It's **NEVER** 
 good to have delimited or mixed data in a single column.  You solve this by fixing the schema where you have a table somewhere that already has sellingUnit and buyingUnit columns, plus the primary key from this table. In the meantime, though, it's important we know exactly what database and version you have, because some more recent versions have JSON support built in.

Comment: im working with periscopedata if that helps